# how to change condition of javascript message box codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to show message box with javascript with some codition from database, this is the example:
controller

```
$email_cek     = $this->model_select->select_member('where email = "$email"');
    if($email_cek == 0){
    $facebook           = $this->input->post('facebook');
    $facebook_cek       = $this->model_select->select_member('where facebook = "$facebook"');
    if($facebook_cek == 0){
        //other script
    }else{
        echo "
        alert('You can't use that facebook account because the account has been used by another member! save aborted!');
        window.location.href='membership';
        ";
    }
    }else{
    echo "
    alert('Your e-mail is exist by another member! save aborted!');
    window.location.href='membership';
    ";
}
```

model

```
public function select_member($id=""){
    $data_member = $this->db->query("select * from member ".$id);
    return $data_member->result_array();
    }
```

I have two forms twitter and facebook, and the existing data in database.
if input type same or exist in database, I want to display a message according to the data that already exists.
but why the message always email messagebox show??

Comment: return form model is an array. so if you want to compare or check the number of data you must use php function to count  total data in array

Answer (score 0):

try model :

```
public function select_member($id=""){
    $data = $this->db->query("select * from member ".$id);
    return $data;
}
```

Controller :

```
$email_cek     = $this->model_select->select_member('where email = "$email"');
if($email_cek->num_rows() == 0){
    $facebook           = $this->input->post('facebook');
    $facebook_cek       = $this->model_select->select_member('where facebook = "$facebook"');
    if($facebook_cek->num_rows() == 0){
        //other script
    }else{
        echo "
        alert('You can't use that facebook account because the account has been used by another member! save aborted!');
        window.location.href='membership';
        ";
    }
}else{
    echo "
    alert('Your e-mail is exist by another member! save aborted!');
    window.location.href='membership';
    ";
}
```